# What does Windows+Home do on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I ran by mistake into a key combination of <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> on Windows 7 and I'm not quite sure what it is supposed to do. Does anybody know?

It looks like it minimizes the last window I had open prior to the current focused window, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> on my Windows 7 system and nothing happened.  However when you press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> it minimizes all but the active window (this is a keyboard equivalent of the "[Aero Shake](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/shake)" gesture) - all windows except for the active window are minimized, and doing it again restores them.

Comment: What is a "Shake" gesture?

Comment: @nhinkle - Thanks, first time I encounter this feature - I'm more of a Keyboard fan :)

Comment: @RonK the shake gesture is where you get hold of the active windows toolbar and shake it side to side, this will minimize all windows but the one you are active on.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. On mine it does nothing. Windows + Home, however minimizes all open windows except the currently focused one. Pressing it again restores them.

Answer (score 3):

[It minimizes all windows except the currently active one.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: Wrong. It's definitely build into Windows, and is the equivalent of Aero Shake.

Comment: @nhinkle - the answer was posted before editing the question, at that time I stated the question was about `Windows`+`End`, and not `Windows`+`Home`

Comment: @RonK, that makes sense I suppose, but if the answer no longer applies, then it should be deleted.

Comment: @nhinkle, impatient much? I posted this last night. Sheesh; could have waited with the down-vote a bit. :roll:

Comment: @Synetechinc that's how it works - if something is wrong, you downvote it. Now that you edited your answer to be correct, I've removed the downvote.

Comment: Thanks, and I know that’s how it works; but I don’t think it’s unreasonable to wait a day, especially for people who clearly check in at least once a day (if the answerer was a 1-point-pony, that would be one thing, but obviously I come here often enough to notice the comment—which is in fact how I saw this—and update). Meh; now if I could just figure out how to *disable* all of Windows’ stupid default hotkeys…

Comment: Nah bottom line the downvote was wrong. It's understandable but once it was pointed out that the answer was to a previous version of the question, the only appropriate response is "my bad".

Answer (score 2):

When hit once, it minimizes all non-active (i.e. background) windows.

When hit again, it the restores the windows back to their original state.

Given that user's typically have a lot of applications open in their GUI environment, this is designed to allow users to focus on one application at a time - *if they so desire*.

Of course, newbies who would benefit from this feature are least likely to know of it's existence :) !